# wavelet fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing, wavelet-analysis

I want to do wavelet Fourier transform of my data but I have few doubts in this. 1)first of all what is octive and voice command here when i am changing value according to that my plot is changing but I don't know how to select this value for my data collection rate is 25fps. Since my data is contain so much oscillation is this code method is good for this?? For your consideration Can you please help me to figure it out the solution for this.I will be highly grateful for you efforts for this. Thank you and for consideration I am adding set of data point for more detail:

I also want to know how mathematica change time to frequency axis??

```
  data = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/xWx0gRTP", "Table", HeaderLines -> 1];
    f[list_, pos_] := Module[{x = list}, x[[All, pos]] = Sequence[]; x]
    fdata = Flatten@f[data, 1];
    cwd = ContinuousWaveletTransform[fdata, MorletWavelet[], {20, 20}, 
      SampleRate -> 25]
    WaveletScalogram[cwd, ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors", 
     ImageSize -> 700]
    ListLinePlot[Total[Abs[#]^2] & /@ Reverse@cwd[All, "Values"], 
      PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 700, BaseStyle -> Thick, 
      PlotStyle -> ColorData[19, "ColorList"], Frame -> True, 
      PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 30}}];
    freq = (1000/(# MorletWavelet[][
             "FourierFactor"])) & /@ (Thread[{Range[6], 1}] /. 
         cwd["Scales"]);

    ticks = Transpose[{Range[Length[freq]], freq}];

    WaveletScalogram[cwd, Frame -> True, 
     FrameTicks -> {{ticks, Automatic}, Automatic}, 
     FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Frequency(Hz)"}, 
     ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", ImageSize -> 700]
```

Comment: The contents of `prticle.xlsx` are the numbers at the bottom of your post?

Comment: yes.this is the data

Comment: I've put your long data in Pastebin; please check if I did not miss anything.

Comment: it seems fine to me.

Comment: I think this data is not accessible.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/xWx0gRTP still works for me.